# JQuery data attribute used for multiple popups but to trigger a specific one on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

### jquery

```
function initPopup() {
//----- OPEN
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function (e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    e.preventDefault();
});
//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function (e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    e.preventDefault();
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initPopup();
});
```

Above is my jquery code that is used to show specific popup data using an attribute.

### HTML

```
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
        <div class="popup-inner">
            <h2>TEST</h2>
            <p>TEST</p>
            <p>TEST</p>
            <a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#" class="close">Close</a>
            <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-2">
            <div class="popup-inner">
             <h2>TEST</h2>
            </div>
        <a data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#" class="close">Close</a>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
```

I would like it so that on a mouseleave event of body that it shows the data-popup="popup-2"

I am very new to jquery but like jumping into the deep end, if you are able to suggest a better way/different way to do this I am happy to learn.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

George

Comment: you are not using mouseleave event in your code. By body, do you mean the html body?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to bind a `mouseleave` event on the html body (I do not understand your use case) what you can do is the following:

```
$("body").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("[data-popup='popup-2']").show();
});
$("body").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("[data-popup='popup-2']").hide();
});
```

This code will reset the state, that mean it will not preserve the opened popup when the mouse reenter the body. If you want to preserve the state, an easy way to do this could be:

```
var isPopupShown = $"([data-popup='popup-2']").is(":visible");
$("body").on("mouseleave", function() {
  isPopupShown = $"([data-popup='popup-2']").is(":visible");
  $("[data-popup='popup-2']").show();
});
$("body").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("[data-popup='popup-2']").show();
  if (!isPopupShown) {
     $("[data-popup='popup-2']").hide();
  }
});
```

This code will show the `popup-2` when the mouse leave the body, and restore the original state when the mouse is inside the body (has not been tested, but thats the idea).

There is many way to achieve a popup, personnally i only use css (js is not needed for a simple popup) for simple case. You can create a piece of reusable css and just reproduce the html structure:

HTML:

```
 <label for="foobaz">click here</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide popup-controller" id="foobaz"/>
  <div class="popup" id="popup1">
    <div>foo</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup-controller {
  display: none;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
}
.popup-controller:checked + .popup {
  display: block;
}
/** This show the popup if the mouse is out the body **/
body:not(:hover) #popup1.popup {
  display: block;
}
```

using this you are free of js [(associated jsbin)](https://jsbin.com/xuhemug/1/edit?html,css,js,output).
Using this code, if the input is checked or the mouse is not in the body, it will show the popup. You just have to use the same html structure to have the same effect on others popup. 
Using this, you can control the popup in JS using `trigger` on the checkbox.

If you are really into JS, i would recommend to create an object and make a code where you specify "popup-1" less as possible. You can do this easily:

```
$( ".popup" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  if ($(event.target).is('.close')) {
    $(this).hide();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

In this case, even if you have many "close" inside your popup, it will close the popup, without the need of specifying `popup-1` (you can keep your `open` code).

Answer (score 0):

Add to pop-up you want to close on leave, another data-attribute something like data-bodyclose (or mettere name). Then in body event, check if the .popup has that attribute, if true close It (maybe better trigger event of data-close-popup child)